# For Loop to score bowling

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

I'm working on a project for a potential internship to take a String input of bowling scores and add them up to a final score. I'm having difficult passing one of my tests and was wondering if you could help me figure out my fault.

The test that is not working is isNinetySix and it is giving me a result of 98 instead. Please help!

```
public class Game {

    private int roll = 0;
    private int[] rolls = new int[21];
    public void rolls(String scoreCard) {
        for (int i=0; i< scoreCard.length(); i++) {
            if (scoreCard.charAt(i) == 'X') {
                rolls[roll++] = 10;
            } else if (scoreCard.charAt(i) == '/') {
                rolls[roll++] = 10;
            } else if (scoreCard.charAt(i) == '-') {
            } else {
                int x = scoreCard.charAt(i);
                rolls[roll++] = x - '0';
            }
        }
    }

    public int score() {
        int score = 0;
        int cursor = 0;
        for (int frame = 0; frame < 10; frame++) {
            if (isStrike(cursor)) { 
                score += 10 + rolls[cursor+1] + rolls[cursor+2];
                cursor ++;
            } else if (isSpare(cursor)) { 
                score += 10 + rolls[cursor+2];
                cursor += 2;
            } else {
                score += rolls[cursor] + rolls[cursor+1];
                cursor += 2;
            }
        }
        return score;
    }

    private boolean isStrike(int cursor) {
        return rolls[cursor] == 10;
    }

    private boolean isSpare(int cursor) {
        return rolls[cursor] + rolls[cursor+1] == 10;
    }

    //Print scores for each frame   
    public void printFrameScore(int[] frame) {
        for (int i = 1; i < frame.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + frame[i]);
        }
    }

    public void displayRolls() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(rolls[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Tests

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class GameTest {

    private Game game;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        game = new Game();
    }

    @Test
    public void isPerfect() {
        game.rolls("X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-XX");
        assertThat(game.score(), is(300));
    }

    @Test
    public void isGutter() {
        game.rolls("00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00");
        assertThat(game.score(), is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void isNinety() {
        game.rolls("45-54-36-27-09-63-81-18-90-72");
        assertThat(game.score(), is(90));
    }


    @Test
    public void isOneFifty(){
        game.rolls("5/-5/-5/-5/-5/-5/-5/-5/-5/-5/-5");
        assertThat(game.score(), is(150));
    }

    @Test
    public void isNinetySix() {
        game.rolls("45-54-36-27-09-63-81-18-90-7/-5");
        assertThat(game.score(), is(96));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you create the tests or are these the tests they gave you?

Comment: This is a good example of a question which has code which isn't working *and* a data set to validate any issues.  Kudos!  Do more things like this in the future Jon!

Comment: I'll try and make a note of this question to come back to it.  It's worth the time to answer at a minimum...

Answer (score 3):

The problem here seems to be that your isSpare() function never returns true because you assigned each `/` a value of 10. The result of the addition of the two rolls in a frame with a spare was more than 10. If I were you I would try to clean up the assignment of `/` to actually be `10 - prev_role_score`. This would be cleaner than making isSpare() check for greater than 10. There are other ways to clean up the code to, you could try to refactor some to impress whoever you submit to.

```java
} else if (scoreCard.charAt(i) == '/') {
    int diff = 10 - rolls[roll - 1];
    rolls[roll++] = diff;
}
```

Comment: @ Jon309 now instead of the last frame being represented by 7 & 10 with a last roll of 5, you will have a frame of  7 & 3 with a last roll of 5. 

If I were quizzing you, I'd want you to represent the spare as 3 because in the real world model, 3 pins would have been knocked down. It makes it easier to explain to someone.

Comment: In the real world, picking up the spare is represented with a slash (/) through the frame.  Doesn't matter if it was one pin, three pins or ten pins.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing in the below block (after your 9th frame, you're at a score of 81). You're code is looking at the index that contains the value `7` and the `/` which you represent as 10, thereby giving you 17 rather than 10 for the spare.

```
        ...
        } else {
            score += rolls[cursor] + rolls[cursor+1];
            cursor += 2;
        }
        ...
```

So, if I were making suggestions, and I'm not sure what the expectations are for your project, I would tell you to think about easier ways to traverse your string by splitting, searching, then adding. Below is a quick example:

```
 public void rolls(String scorecard) {
    String [] framesets = scorecard.split("-");

    //hunt for special cases like spare and strikes

    //do work to hold your scores
}
```